# What am I missing here? (Topology, connectedness)

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let's say I have a space $E=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with topology $\mathcal{T}=\{E,\emptyset\}$. The connected components of $E$ are $\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\}$. Since the closure of a connected component is again equal to the connected componented I should have that,$\overline{\{a\}}=\{a\},\overline{\{b\}}=\{b\},\overline{\{c\}}=\{c\},\overline{\{d\}}=\{d\}$. And thus $\overline{\{a\}}^c \in \mathcal{T}$ since the complement of a closed set has to be open. But $$\overline{\{a\}}^c = E \setminus \{a\}=\{b,c,d\} \notin \mathcal{T}.$$

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your components are wrong so the rest of your argument is, too.

Comment: Oh ok. So what would then the connected components  of $a$ be? since $\{a\}$ is surely a connected subset containing $a$ thus it has to be in the connected component $C_a$ of a?

Comment: You don't speak of connected components of points, necessarily.  If you do, you mean the largest connected subset containing that particular point.  A component is a connected subset contained in no larger connected subset (roughly).  For your case, the only component is $E$ itself. So, the connected component containing $a$ is $E$.  And yes, there are other connected subsets containing $a$, but the component has to be the largest one.

Comment: Oh I see. $E$ itself is connected. Ok thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument shows that what you considered as connected components are not. A connected component is maximal (ordered by inclusion), i.e that if $C$ is a connected component and $C\subset S$ but $C\neq S$, then $S$ is necessarly not connected.

Note that your topological space is connected. That's because you can't write $E$ as a union of nonempty disjoint open sets, because $E$ is the only nonempty open set in your topology. So, despite $\{a\}$ being connected, it is not a maximal component as $\{a\}\subset E$ with $E\neq\{a\}$ yet $E$ is connected. In fact, a connected space has exactly one connected component, namely itself.

Also note that in a finite topological space, the connected components are also open.